# Having different models for request and response - backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
//A backbone model
var RequestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

//A backbone model
var ResponseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

RequestModel.save({
    success: function (ResponseModel ) {
        alert(ResponseModel .toJSON());
    }
})
```

Can i have a separate Model for Request and Response, as both Request and Response does not match. Its a total RPC call and not a CRUD operation.

Answer (score 4):

I've thought about this same problem before, and I feel there isn't a **great** way to achieve this in Backbone. The best I've come up with is to implement a `fromResponse` and `toRequest` method on the model, and override [`model.parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) and [`model.sync`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-sync) to map the model object to them. Something like:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  fromResponse: function(responseAttrs) {
    var modelAttrs = {}; //map response attributes to modelAttrs
    return modelAttrs;
  },

  toRequest: function() {
    //map model attributes to response attributes here
    var modelAttrs = this.toJSON();
    var responseAttrs = {}; //map models attributes to requestAttrs
    return responseAttrs;
  },

  parse: function(response) {
    return this.fromResponse(response);
  },

  sync: function(method, model, options) { 
    options = options || {};
    options.data = this.toRequest();
    Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
  }
});
```

If the `parse` and `sync` are overridden in some kind of a base class, then you only need to implement the `fromResponse` and `toRequest` mappers for each model.

Another option would be to override `Backbone.sync` altogether, and map each `Model` type to some kind of `ModelRequestMapper` and `ModelResponseMapper` object to (de-)serialize each model. I feel that would be more complicated, but might scale better, if you have lots of models.

/Code sample not tested

Comment: i think when having different request and response, its better to go with plain ajax call and btw can i have a common model for both of them... and yet not making it complicated.

Comment: +1 for answer. I might not bother with the toRequest and fromResponse methods, but ```sync``` and ```parse``` exist for the purpose of abstracting your endpoint to the model. Of course you could use a plan ajax call, but then what's the point of using Backbone?